# How can I pass primery key to url for editing information about objects?

Tags: python, django

I have a model called Porumbei and I want to make a view to edit those objects.According to my low knowledge of django, how can I write this view passing the primery key to url? The url I wish should look like /porumbei/editare/pk/
My view:

```
def editareporumbei(request, pk):
    porumbel = get_object_or_404(Porumbei, pk=pk)

    if request.method == "POST":
    form = AdaugaPorumbel(request.POST, instance=porumbel)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect("dashboard")
    else:
    form = AdaugaPorumbel(instance=porumbel)
    context = {
        'form' : form,
    }
    template = loader.get_template("editare_porumbei.html")
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

#Link in the template. The template shows all Porumbei in the database
    <td>
        <a href="{% url 'editareporumbei' pk=porumbel.pk %}" class="mr-15" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Editează"> <i class="icon-pencil"></i> </a>
    </td>

# My url

    path('porumbei/editare/(?P<pk>\d+)/', views.editareporumbei, name='editareporumbei'),
```

> Reverse for 'editareporumbei' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not
>   found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['porumbei/editare/(?P[0-9]+)/$']

If I directly access `porumbei/editare/5` it shows me the form for editing data but I want to take me to the page when I click a button. The button is in the page where all Porumbei are listed.

Comment: show the view from which you are sending the 'porumbel' object

Comment: <td> {{ porumbel.pk }} </td>   try to render this in html... what is result ?

Comment: The porumbel comes from porumbel = get_object_or_404(Porumbei, pk=pk) that is in editareporumbei view. It's listed on top of my question

Answer (score 0):

The path is not correct. Try:

```
path('porumbei/editare/<int:pk>/', views.editareporumbei, name='editareporumbei'),
```

or:

```
re_path('porumbei/editare/(?P<pk>\d+)/', views.editareporumbei, name='editareporumbei'),
```

Comment: No, it still not working. I think the problem is <td>
        <a href="{% url 'editareporumbei' pk=porumbel.pk %}" class="mr-15" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Editează"> <i class="icon-pencil"></i> </a>
    </td> The primery key might not be passed to the url

Comment: <td> <a href="{% url 'editareporumbei' pk=porumbel.pk %}" class="mr-15" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Editează"> <i class="icon-pencil"></i> </a> </td> is wrtitten correct, i tried it out. May be you use namespaces or app_name? Then you should add them to url, as exaple: <a href="{% url 'app_name:editareporumbei' pk=porumbel.pk %}"

Comment: The pk=porumbel.pk didn't return any pk. The view that display all Porumbei has item = Porumbei.objects.all(). Correct url are <td> <a href="{% url 'editareporumbei' item.id_porumbel %}" class="mr-15" data-toggle="tooltip" data-original-title="Editează"> <i class="icon-pencil"></i> </a> </td> where id_porumbel is the primary key of the table in database. Thanks for all